# Search particular text in all files having same name [Sublime text 3]

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to search for some text (*foo*) in all the files having same name in a directory (*bar.yml*).
I tried using `*/bar.yml, **/bar.yml, *bar.yml` and a whole lot of other combinations in the **Where** part of **find_all**, but nothing seems to be working.

Is there a way to do this in Sublime Text 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime looks for files inside a folder structure recursively, as far as I know.

Open the parent folder structure via `File/Open Folder...` and open the search dialog via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Now add your search term to `Find:` and your filter `bar.yml` to `Where:`. That should do it.

Comment: That is for when the `bar.yml` is directly inside the folder. I need to search inside all the subdirectories having `bar.yml` in the current folder.

Comment: Sublime traverses all sub-directories of your selected parent folder. I just replicated the workflow I posted in Sublime 3.2.2.